# How can I use $().bind and mouseup to remove contextmenu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, contextmenu, dom-events

I need to use the $().bind method. I do not wish to use another plugin. I simply want to add both a left click and a right click function. Here is my function handler. I also must disable the context menu. Here is my $().bind function (I am attempting to extend jQuery's full calendar to allow me to bind any jsEvent to its own events, as it only exposes 3 js events.)

```
if (has(eventBind)) {
            $.each(eventBind, function (eventString, eventFunction) {                
                options.eventRender = function (calEvent, element) {
                    element.bind(eventString, { calEvent: calEvent }, eventFunction);
                }
            });
        }  
}
```

If i define eventBind like this, then what happens is that function A gets called if i right click and function B gets called if I left click

```
 eventBind: {
     mouseup:  function eventClick(e) {
        if (e.button === 2) {
           //execute function A
        } else {
           //execute function B
        } 
    }
```

I apologize if the order of my code does not really make sense, but I just want to know what to do. I tried to define the following

```
   eventBind: {
         mouseup:  function eventClick(e) {
             if (e.button === 2) {
                //execute function A
             } else {
                //execute function B
             } 
         },
         contextmenu: function() { return false; }
     }    
}
```

But this also disabled the previously defined "mouseup" from executing correctly.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could stop all context menus on a target element with `$(target).bind("contextmenu",false);` I don't understand what the rest of your code is supposed to be doing.

Comment: I believe you are disabling the contextmenu property (despite being sort of roundabout) and your problem is most likely with `mouseup: this.eventClick` because `this` probably does not point to what you think it does.

Comment: I rewrote my code without this so it doesnt confuse you @jbabey I basically try to keep business logic functions and bindings to libraries (like jQuery) seperate

Comment: @KevinB fullcalander for jQuery creates a dom element on a calendar and I want to bind any event to it which is defined as a property in the object eventBind and pass the calendar's 'calEvent' (its data) as data to pass to the function handler for that event

Comment: your $.each is overriding the options.eventRender property on each iteration, is that intended? it'l only be equal to the last thing in the eventBind object.

Comment: @kevinB I thought something like that was happening, I need now to figure out how I can pass eventData to multiple events defined by eventBind, and use $().bind to take in multiple events instead of one

Comment: Could you simply move the $.each to inside of the options.eventRender function?

Comment: @KevinB wow, thats so obvious. I was rushing before for some reason and  didn't realize I was doing that....I was certain that mouseup and contextmenu were incompatible for some reason. Thanks so much Kevin! Don't know how I didn't catch that before, I feel idiotic now.

Comment: @KevinB I have to begin to learn the problem isn't the program, the problem is probably me. =)

Comment: okay i made the change and it still doesnt seem to work. *sigh

Comment: Just a comment to say I used your eventClick code to *force* a context menu to appear in Chrome 51 for Windows, in which I believe the mouseUp event fires before the contextmenu event, causing a javascript to fire when the context menu is what is really being requested. Very useful, thanks.